# Integral of $\sec x$ using certain identity

Tags: calculus

Use the identity $\sec x=\frac{\cos x}{1-\sin^2x}$ to prove that the integral of $\sec x$ equals $\frac12\ln\frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}$. I tried to manipulate it but nothing seems to work. Help.

Comment: Your questions seems to be answered on this thread :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492942/verify-%E2%88%ABsecx-1-2-ln-1sinx-1-sinx-c/1492947#1492947

Comment: Basically the author explicitly wrote for you the identity $$\sec x=g'(x)f(g(x))$$ where $f$ is a function such that $\int f$ is assumed to be easily sovable for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\sec(x)=\frac{\cos (x)}{1-\sin^2(x)}=\frac{\cos (x)}{(1+\sin(x))(1-\sin(x))}$$ Now $$\frac{1}{(1+\sin(x))(1-\sin(x))}=\frac{A}{1+\sin(x)}+\frac{B}{1-\sin(x)}$$ Solve for $A,B$ and later, remember that $\cos(x)=\left(\sin(x)\right)'$.